# Gradle task fails to generate web application from UML model NullPointerException possibly due to mismatched depencies

Tags: spring, gradle, tomcat

I am trying to generate a web application from an UML model using an internal tool that requires a Gradle task. However, when I run the task, I encounter errors that prevent the web application from being generated successfully. The following error messages are displayed:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-jetbrains/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And this is the error that comes up during debugging:

```
isSatisfiedBy:41, JarTypeFileSpec (org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin)
Exception=java.lang.NullPointerException
file=/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar
```

Can anyone help me understand what's causing these errors and how I can fix them to successfully generate the web application?

I assume there is a problem with the javax dependency that i get from a nexus. But I am stumped what the actual problem is as I am not familar with the code base. here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'de.rwth.se.umlp-tool' version "$mc_version"

  id 'application'
  id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.2.1'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${spring_version}"
}

repositories {
  if(("true").equals(getProperty('useLocalRepo'))) {
    println "Using local repo for dependencies"
    mavenLocal()
  }
  maven {
    credentials.username mavenUser
    credentials.password mavenPassword
    url "https://nexus.se.rwth-aachen.de/content/groups/umlp"
  }
}

application {
  mainClass = 'de.rwth.sle23.exercise1.LibraryServerApplication'
}

dependencies {
  implementation(group: 'umlp', name: 'umlp-rte', version: mc_version){
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-simple"
  }
  implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'

  compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:$spring_version")

  implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: spring_version
  implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version: spring_version
  implementation group: 'org.springframework.shell', name: 'spring-shell-starter', version: '2.1.7'
  implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: spring_version

  //Netty Dns  Compatibility
  runtimeOnly group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.89.Final'
  compileOnly("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1")
}

task generateUMLPJava(type: UMLPTask) {
  input = file("../models/")
  outputDir = layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated-sources/")
  configTemplate = "umlp/UMLPConfig4teaching.ftl"
  hwcDir = layout.projectDirectory.dir("src/main/java/")
  tmplDir = layout.projectDirectory.dir("src/templates/")
}

sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs += [generateUMLPJava.outputDir]
  main.resources.srcDirs += [generateUMLPJava.outputDir.dir("frontend4teaching")]
  main.resources.srcDirs += [generateUMLPJava.outputDir.dir("resources")]
}

task runShellApi(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun) {
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  standardInput = System.in
  mainClass = 'de.rwth.sle23.exercise1.LibraryShellAPIApplication'
}

task runServer {
  dependsOn(bootRun {
    systemProperty "spring.shell.interactive.enabled", "false"
  })
}

jib {
  container{
    mainClass = "de.rwth.sle23.exercise1.LibraryServerApplication"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.